# Using empty gridLayout, but will hold ImageIcon and store information later. Can i modify the size?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, grid-layout

Below is my code, which is meant to create a grid on the left hand side, which is does, however the two grids are made very long and thin, and even when later on i add the image to it it remains the same size! 
I dont know whether there's some way of changing it, and i tried to use the gridBagLayout but I've never used it before and i wasn't sure how i could apply my current code to it!
 I'm not quite sure how to explain it, as i'm a beginner in java and have only just been learning it at uni for a short while. If you need more information I'm happy to provide it.

I know that the grid means everything is the same size, but is there any way of actually setting that size of controlling the size of it?

```
public static int ROWS = 3;
public static int ROWS1 = 1;
public static int COLUMNS = 4;
pnlLorry = new JPanel();


    pnlLorry.setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS1, COLUMNS));
    pnlLorry.setSize(100, 400);
    pnlLorry.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    pnlLorry.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));
    for (int row = 0; row < largeVehicle.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < largeVehicle[row].length; column++) {
            ImagePanel pnlLorryImage = new ImagePanel();
            pnlLorryImage.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener(row, column));
            pnlLorryImage.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            pnlLorry.add(pnlLorryImage, row * (largeVehicle.length - 1) + column);
        }
    }
    pnlCars = new JPanel();
    pnlCars.setSize(400, 400);
    pnlCars.setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLUMNS));
    pnlCars.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    pnlCars.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));
    for (int row = 0; row < carVehicle.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < carVehicle[row].length; column++) {
            ImagePanel pnlCarImage = new ImagePanel();
            pnlCarImage.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener(row, column));
            pnlCarImage.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            pnlCars.add(pnlCarImage, row * (carVehicle.length - 1) + column);
        }
    }

    GridLayout = new GridLayout(2, 1);
    vehicleMain.setLayout(GridLayout);
    vehicleMain.add(pnlLorry);
    vehicleMain.add(pnlCars);
```

Comment: GridLayout calculates its preferredSize based on the largest width and height dimensions of its grid cell contents. You could place one "dummy" component in the grid with an appropriate size on creation, perhaps a JLabel or better a `Box.createRigidArea(...)`

Comment: please share minimal testable code and share links of the snapshots of final design  if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the two grids are made very long and thin

I am surprised why It's not working with `GridLayout` because by default `GridLayout` assigns equal size for all the components in percentage.

Whenever you uses Layout Manager then there is no need to call `setSize()`. Just leave it for Layout Manager to set the size.

Just remove the `setSize()` method calls.

> i tried to use the gridBagLayout but I've never used it before and i wasn't sure how i could apply my current code to it!

In below sample code I have changed the last part that might help you to solve it.

Change:

```
GridLayout = new GridLayout(2, 1);
vehicleMain.setLayout(GridLayout);
vehicleMain.add(pnlLorry);
vehicleMain.add(pnlCars);
```

To:

```
GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
vehicleMain.setLayout(gridBagLayout);

GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;// set VERTICAL/HORIZONTAL as per need
gc.weightx=1; // 100% horizontally
gc.weighty=1; // 100% vertically

gc.gridx = 0; // first column
gc.gridy = 0; // first row
vehicleMain.add(pnlLorry, gc);// notice second parameter

gc.gridx = 0; // first column 
gc.gridy = 1; // second row
vehicleMain.add(pnlCars, gc);// notice second parameter
```

---

It's better explained under *Swing Tutorial* on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) with detail example.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for replying so quickly.
I've looked into changing the whole layout to gridbag but im not confident enough in my programming to make it do what i want it to! i tried implementing your code, however the only change was that the grid were now beside themselves and they are still both long and thin :(